# Find duplicates in pandas with condition (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the number of duplicates for `article_id` for each `merchant_id`, where the `zip_code` is not identical. Please see example below:

**Table**

```
merchant_id     article_id   zip_code 
1               4555         1000
1               4555         1003
1               4555         1002
1               3029         1000
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1005
2               7539         1002
2               1232         1006
3               5555         1000
3               5555         1001
3               5555         1002
3               5555         1003
```

**Output Table**

```
merchant_id     count_duplicate
1                3
2                2
3                4
```

So far I was able to return all duplicate rows - see code below:

```
df[df.duplicated('product_id',keep=False)==True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `groupby` with `nunique` and then filter (`query`) only the groups `> 1`. `nunique` stands for "number of unique values".

```
dfn = (
    df.groupby(['merchant_id', 'article_id'])['zip_code'].nunique()
    .reset_index(name='count_duplicate')
    .query('count_duplicate > 1')
)

   merchant_id  article_id  count_duplicate
1            1        4555                3
3            2        7539                2
4            3        5555                4
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Do you have an idea how to count duplicates where the zip_code is identical. I.e. counting for each zip_code and merchant_id the number of product_id duplicates?

Comment: Glad it works. Regarding your second question, I see that as a new question, and this one as answered. Feel free to post a new question and I will have look at it! Btw dont forget to accept this one if it helped you :)